# Animating multiple Ball objects in repaint (one at a time)

Tags: java, animation, paintcomponent, repaint

I have a program where I need to animate ball objects. I have a Ball() class that handles the movement of the ball as it drops downwards, then an Animation() class that paints the ball and background, then repaints using a timer for moving the ball.

I need each ball to animate, then the ball stops at the bottom of the screen, start another ball at the top of the screen. I assume that I need an array of Ball objects so that the balls don't disappear when instantiating a new Ball. My problem is that I can't figure out how to instantiate another Ball object in my code. I have tried multiple methods and failed. I finally got my code back to the normal state with one working ball and wish for some help!

Last Note: The user will dictate the amount of balls from another menu class, which will then pass the integer value to the Animation() class constructor. I'd like to create an array of balls using this integer value. Is this the correct method of thinking? The paintComponent() method cannot see an array inside the constructor, so I'd have to make a method to pass the array to the paintComponent()?

**Animation class:**

```
public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

// Global Variables
private Timer timer;
Random rand = new Random();
private int delay = 0;
ActionListener updateAnim;
Ball myBall = new Ball();

// Animation Constructor
public Animation()
{
    timer = new Timer(delay,this);
    timer.setInitialDelay(500);
    timer.start();
}

// Ball will roll down/left/right
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{       
    int x = rand.nextInt(2);
    myBall.rollDown();

    if (x == 0)
        myBall.rollRight();
    else
        myBall.rollLeft();

    myBall.finalDescent();
    repaint();
}

// Draws Ball object, and Background
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    myBall.drawBall(g);

    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // Background

    int counter = 0; // count what number peg we are painting
    int row = 1;     // calculate what row we are creating
    int rowSpacer = 55;
    boolean evenRow = false;
    int columnSpacer = 60;

    // DRAW PEGS TO SCREEN (4 rows of 8, 4 rows of 7)
    for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
    {
        // For odd rows
        if (row % 2 == 1)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(rowSpacer - 40, columnSpacer, 10, 10);
            rowSpacer += 40;
            counter++;
        }
        // For Even rows
        else 
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(rowSpacer - 20, columnSpacer, 10, 10);
            rowSpacer += 40;
            counter++;
        }

        // Check to see if we are finished with odd row
        if (counter % 8 == 0 && evenRow == false)
        {
            row++;
            rowSpacer = 55;
            columnSpacer += 60;
            evenRow = true;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else if(counter % 7 == 0 && evenRow == true) 
        {
            row++;
            rowSpacer = 55;
            columnSpacer += 60;
            evenRow = false;
            counter = 0;
        }
    } // END DRAWING PEGS TO SCREEN

    // DRAW RECTANGULAR WALLS TO SCREEN
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    // Wall Color
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 5, 760);   // LEFT Wall
    g.fillRect(315, 0, 5, 760); // RIGHT Wall
    //g.fillRect(0, 0, 315, 5);   // TOP Wall
    g.fillRect(0, 755, 320, 5); // BOTTOM Wall

    // DRAW BOTTOM GATES
    int gateSeperator = 35;
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(gateSeperator, 500, 10, 255);
        gateSeperator += 40;
    }   

    } // END paintComponent()
} // END Animation Class
```

**Ball Class:**

```
public class Ball{

private int x = 85, y = -30;
private int velx = 0, vely = 0;
private boolean downInMotion = false;
private boolean rightInMotion = false;
private boolean leftInMotion = false;
private boolean ballStopped = false;
private boolean finalDescent = false;
private boolean horizontalLast = true;
private int hCounter = 0, vCounter = 0;
private int traveled = 0;

public void moveBall(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

public void rollDown()
{
    if(leftInMotion == false && rightInMotion == false && ballStopped == false
            && finalDescent == false && horizontalLast == true)
    {
        downInMotion = true;
        vely = 1;
        velx = 0;

        if (traveled == ((vCounter + 60) + hCounter))
        {
            vely = 0;
            downInMotion = false;
            horizontalLast = false;
            vCounter += 60;
            System.out.println("Turning Right");
        }
        else
        {
            moveBall(x, y + vely);
            traveled += 1;
            System.out.println("Traveled: " + traveled);
        }
    }
} // END rollDown()

// The Ball will roll to the right
public void rollRight()
{
    if (leftInMotion == false && downInMotion == false && ballStopped == false 
            && finalDescent == false && horizontalLast == false)
    {
        rightInMotion = true;
        vely = 0;
        velx = 1;

        if (traveled == (vCounter + (hCounter + 20)))
        {
            velx = 0;
            rightInMotion = false;
            horizontalLast = true;
            hCounter += 20;
            System.out.println("Going Down");
        }
        else
        {
            moveBall(x + velx, y);
            traveled += 1;
            System.out.println("Traveled: " + traveled);
        }
    }
} // END rollRight()

public void rollLeft()
{
    if (rightInMotion == false && downInMotion == false && ballStopped == false
            && finalDescent == false && horizontalLast == false)
    {
        leftInMotion = true;
        vely = 0;
        velx = -1;

        if (traveled == (vCounter + (hCounter + 20)))
        {
            velx = 0;
            leftInMotion = false;
            horizontalLast = true;
            hCounter += 20;
            System.out.println("Turning Right");
        }
        else
        {
            moveBall(x + velx, y);
            traveled += 1;
            System.out.println("Traveled: " + traveled);
        }
    }
} // END rollLeft()

public void finalDescent()
{
    if (traveled >= 640 && ballStopped == false)
    {           
        finalDescent = true;

        vely = 1;
        velx = 0;

        System.out.println("FINAL DESCENT");

        if (traveled == 915)
        {
            vely = 0;
            System.out.println("Ball Stopped");
            stopBall();
        }
        else
        {
            moveBall(x, y + vely);
            traveled += 1;
            System.out.println("Traveled: " + traveled);
        }
    }
} // END finalDescent()

public void stopBall()
{
    ballStopped = true;
}

public void drawBall(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably forgot to instantiate every ball in array...

```
//declare a field
private List<Ball> balls;

Animation(int count) {
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    //this is probably what you've missed...
    balls.add(new Ball());
  }
}


...
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  ...
  //paint as usual
  for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i) {
    //this is probably what you've missed...
    balls[i].drawBall(g);
  }
}

...
public void someMethod() {
    if (youWantToAddBall) {
        balls.add(new Ball());
    }
    if (youWantToRemoveBall) {
        Ball ballToRemove = ...; //
        balls.remove(ballToRemove);
    }
}
```

[EDIT:]
I've read your question more carefully, and here are some more thoughts. I think it's better to separate current moving balls from other ones. So you can move them separately, but still draw them altogether. Also you will need to add check method to `Ball` class to determine if ball is dropped.

```
List<Ball> movingBalls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
List<Ball> allBalls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

Animation(int count) {
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    Ball newBall = new Ball();

    allBalls.add(newBall);
    //all new balls are initially moving
    movingBalls.add(newBall);
  }
}

// Ball will roll down/left/right
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       
    // we need to use new list here, because we can't add to movingBalls list, while iterating
    List<Ball> newBalls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    //using iterators here, so we can remove balls, while iterating
    Iterator it = movingBalls.iterator()
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      Ball ball = it.next();

      int x = rand.nextInt(2);
      ball.rollDown();

      if (x == 0)
          ball.rollRight();
      else
          ball.rollLeft();

      ball.finalDescent();

      //now check if ball is dropped and create new one...
      if (ball.isDropped()) {
        //remove current ball from movingBalls list
        it.remove(); 

        //create new ball
        newBalls.add(new Ball());
      }
    }

    movingBalls.addAll(newBalls);
    allBalls.addAll(newBalls);

    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  ...
  //paint as usual
  for (int i = 0; i < allBalls.length; ++i) {
    //this is probably what you've missed...
    allBalls[i].drawBall(g);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the top code, but the paintComponent would instantiate all the balls at the same time, right? Even if they did, i'm not sure how i'd get them to animate individually using the actionPerformed() method in the Animation() class. Thank you for the reply btw! This helps already.

Comment: I added in your code and it seems to work fine, however, when I add a similar FOR loop in the actionPerformed() method, all the balls drop at the same time. Though this is awesome to watch, it's not quite what I want. Very amusing :)

Comment: To be able to add new balls, you can actually use lists. I'll edit the code

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with lists in Java, so the latter might be bad. Maybe I can pass a boolean that marks the end of a ball's animation cycle? I'm new to animation, so i'm unaware to how this might work as well - I usually just keep trying until I get it to work most times. Once again, thank you for your assistance in all this.

Comment: It's better to learn how to use lists and collections in general, they are quite usefull. In particular, you can't modify arrays, which you need for this task. I've added one more code fragment to show how you can get what you want with lists.

Comment: Thanks for everything! I will accept your answer after I get back to my computer and text that out. I'm on stack exchange atm, so sometime tomorrow!